# Bootstrap components

Tags: bootstrap-5, bootstrap-carousel, bootstrap-slider

Trying to build e-commerce website using bootstrap. I want to know:-

1- how to make items sliders
[item-Slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROqV2.png)

2- Navbar drop menu expanded.
[Expanded Drop-menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WT5sO.jpg)

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

for question 1:

Just put multiple items in `.carousel-item`

```html
<div class="carousel-item">
  <ul>
    <li>first item</li>
    <li>second item</li>
    <li>...</li>
  </ul>
</div>
...
```

for question 2:

Dropdown compoent can't expanded by default because it's expanded via calculate it's position by JS. You can consider to use another components, likes `Accordion`,`List group` or the thirdy package, like FastBootstrap's [Menu component](https://fastbootstrap.com/components/menu/).